# How to get resolution when the video quality of a video changed automatically in android youtube API?

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am trying to develop an app using Android's YouTube API.and wanna get the resolution information when quality of a video changes automatically, but I haven't found the interface in YouTube Player API.

Please let me know if there is any other way to refer to the Youtube API or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the resolution of a video by using the `contentDetails` as a `part` parameter in the [`Videos: list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list).

```
"contentDetails": {
"duration": "PT3M26S",
"dimension": "2d",
"definition": "hd",
"caption": "false",
"licensedContent": true
}
```

You can see in the [`definition`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#videoDefinition) part under the `contentDetails` the resolution of a video, but the value for it is either a high definition(**hd**) or standard definition(**sd**). You cannot get the video resolution as 360p, 720p etc. But the 720p and 1080p is considered as HD.

Comment: I know that the information is not the resolution information of the actual Play, but the resolution information in the Uploaded Video List.

Can I get resolution information from that information (if the Quality changes automatically) while it is playing?

Comment: While it is playing? Sadly to say but I think you cannot get the specific resolution.